# NullableAttribute is declared in another module and needs to be imported - ILRepack

Tags: c#, mono.cecil, ilmerge, ilrepack

So I'm using ILRepack, which as far as I understand, uses Mono.Cecil behind the scenes, to do ILWeaving. I'm running into a problem in my project, which ends up resulting in the following error as soon as I import, for example, Newtonsoft.Json version 13.0.1:

```cs
INFO: Writing output assembly to disk
System.ArgumentException: Member 'System.Void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute::.ctor(System.Byte)' is declared in another module and needs to be imported
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.LookupToken(IMetadataTokenProvider provider)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddCustomAttributes(ICustomAttributeProvider owner)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddConstraints(GenericParameter generic_parameter, GenericParamConstraintTable table)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddGenericParameters()
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildTypes()
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildModule()
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildMetadata()
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.BuildMetadata(ModuleDefinition module, MetadataBuilder metadata)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.Write(ModuleDefinition module, Disposable`1 stream, WriterParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.WriteModule(ModuleDefinition module, Disposable`1 stream, WriterParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write(String fileName, WriterParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.Write(String fileName, WriterParameters parameters)
   at ILRepacking.ILRepack.Repack()
   at ILRepack.Lib.Task.ILRepack.Execute()
```

All I'm doing is adding it as a PackageReference, and when building in release mode, I get this error.

I realize the error message is quite specific, but after hours of attempts at solving this, I have been unable to. My biggest problem is I have no idea what "another module" means exactly.
This is a completely empty project except using the ILRepack package and importing Newtonsoft.Json.
It targets `netstandard2.0`, which I need to be the target. I cannot change this to a newer version for... reasons.
Building in release mode without Newtonsoft.Json works.
It also works building in debug, where ILRepack doesn't execute.
So this means that the necessary Attribute *must* exist, otherwise it wouldn't have compiled in debug, right?

I tried defining this attribute in my project manually, like so:

```cs
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [AttributeUsage(
        AttributeTargets.Class |
        AttributeTargets.Event |
        AttributeTargets.Field |
        AttributeTargets.GenericParameter |
        AttributeTargets.Parameter |
        AttributeTargets.Property |
        AttributeTargets.ReturnValue,
        AllowMultiple = false,
        Inherited = false)]
    public class NullableAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public readonly byte[] NullableFlags;
        public NullableAttribute(byte flag)
        {
            NullableFlags = new byte[] { flag };
        }
        public NullableAttribute(byte[] flags)
        {
            NullableFlags = flags;
        }
    }
}
```

but even then, I get the above error. So where *is* Mono.Cecil actually looking for this attribute? And why is it not even enough for me to manually define it, in my project?

The ILRepack configuration I use is this:

```xml
  <Target Name="MergeTheThing" AfterTargets="build" Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('Release'))">
    <ItemGroup>
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)" />
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)*.dll" Exclude="$(OutputPath)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <LibraryPath Include="$(OutputPath)" />
      <LibraryPath Include="$(VINTAGE_STORY)/Lib/" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <DoNotInternalizeAssemblies Include="VintagestoryAPI.dll" />
      <DoNotInternalizeAssemblies Include="VintagestoryLib.dll" />
      <DoNotInternalizeAssemblies Include="VSSurvivalMod.dll" />
      <DoNotInternalizeAssemblies Include="VSEssentials.dll" />
      <DoNotInternalizeAssemblies Include="VSCreativeMod.dll" />
      <DoNotInternalizeAssemblies Include="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
      <DoNotInternalizeAssemblies Include="0Harmony.dll" />
      <DoNotInternalizeAssemblies Include="protobuf-net.dll" />
      <DoNotInternalizeAssemblies Include="System.Data.SQLite.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ILRepack Parallel="true"
              DebugInfo="true"
              Verbose="true"
              Internalize="true"
              InternalizeExclude="@(DoNotInternalizeAssemblies)"
              Wildcards="true"
              InputAssemblies="@(InputAssemblies)"
              LibraryPath="@(LibraryPath)"
              KeyFile="$(AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile)"
              TargetKind="SameAsPrimaryAssembly"
              OutputFile="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName)$(TargetExt)"
              LogFile="output.txt"/>
  </Target>
```

What options do I have for telling Mono.Cecil where to look for this attribute?
Or can I somehow make it ignore the attribute completely? I don't need to use it, I just need this to compile properly.

See the attached output.txt for a log file:
[output.txt](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/files/6839911/output.txt)
Inside this log file, I also noticed that it actually does import the NullableAttribute that I manually defined: `Importing System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute from TestSolution4.dll`, but why doesn't Mono.Cecil just use this one then?

Any help greatly appreciated!